# PHP - How to compare database content to a user file upload?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare the user uploaded a file with the database, but 
the uploaded file should not get stored into the database.

```
So, for example, my database looks like this
NAME    CONTENT
KEY     helloworld

and the user uploads a text file which contains this:

youhello
```

So now, since the database and the textfile has the word `hello` in it
it should output something like `matched`

I'm having issue implementing this logic

```
function checking_for_virus($connection){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    if(isset($_POST['userFile'])){
        if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type']!= 'text/plain') {
            echo "<span>File could not be accepted ! Please upload any '*.txt' file.</span>";
            exit();
        }
        /* IMPLEMENTATION OF THE LOGIC TO COMPARE THE FILE FROM THE DATABASE CONTENT*/
    }
}
```

The expected result should be matched since both the database content
and text file has `hello` in it.

Could anyone please provide me with an explanation to implement this.

Comment: Can explain more on your definition of `matched`?

Comment: so when the user upload text file content matches with the database content, lets say 'hello', the output will just echo "matched" with the Name which is KEY.